# Avoid passing parameters multiple times when calling xsl template repeatedly

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a template that is being called with (not an exaggeration) roughly 100 parameters or so. I need to call this template several times as I need to alter the parent node(s) - sometimes it does not exist, sometimes there are several nodes, and there are several values that can be taken.

For example an example snippet of the current setup:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$test='1'">
    <body1>
      <body3>
        <xsl:call-template name="template1">
          <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$previouslydefined1" />
           .
           . 
           .
          <xsl:with-param name="param100" select="$previouslydefined100" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      <body3>
    </body1>
  </when>
  <xsl:when test="$test='2'">
    <body2>
      <xsl:call-template name="template1">
        <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$previouslydefined1" />
         .
         .
         .
        <xsl:with-param name="param100" select="$previouslydefined100" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </body2>
  </when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-template name="template1">
      <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$previouslydefined1" />
       .
       .
       .
      <xsl:with-param name="param100" select="$previouslydefined100" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I feel there must be a better way of doing this (probably several) without typing out a huge chunk of parameters repeatedly, but I'm drawing a blank.

I have two methods which I know don't work, but possibly there is a modified implementation that would.

Choose statement around the nodes individually (fails - bad syntax):

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$test='1'">
    <body1>
  </when>
  <xsl:when test="$test='2'">
    <body2>
  </when>
  <xsl:otherwise/>
    <xsl:call-template name="template1">
      <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$previouslydefined1" />
       .
       .
       .
      <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$previouslydefined100" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$test='1'">
    </body1>
  </when>
  <xsl:when test="$test='2'">
    </body2>
  </when>
  <xsl:otherwise/>
</xsl:choose>
```

Use a value to set the node (fails - values can be empty in which case tag should not exist):

```
<xsl:element name="{$node}">
  <xsl:element name="{$node2}">
    <xsl:call-template name="template1">
      <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$previouslydefined1" />
       .
       .
       .
      <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$previouslydefined100" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

I also understand that it should be possible to use tunnelling (maybe) - I'm checking this possibility now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I messed up my original implementation of setting the nodes via a parameter. It is possible to leave the values empty in which case the nodes are not created which is what I was originally looking for. By using the maximum number of possible nodes necessary and then filling as necessary I can the template only once:

```
<xsl:element name="{$node}">
  <xsl:element name="{$node2}">
    <xsl:call-template name="template1">
      <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$previouslydefined1" />
        .
        .
        .
      <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$previouslydefined100" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```